# Complex roots and sign of a function

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let's say we have the polynomial $$P(x)=\pm a_1x^1 \pm a_2x^2 \pm \cdots \pm a_nx^n.$$

Assume that this polynomial have both complex and real roots.

Does complex roots effect this polynomial's sign?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the sign of a polynomial?

Comment: I mean, the function $x^2-1$ is positive for $x>1$, then the sign of $x^2-1$ is positive for $x>1$ in my terms :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the reals, every polynomial factors into linear and quadratic factors.  The linear factors correspond to real roots and the quadratic factors correspond to conjugate pairs of complex roots.

The quadratic factors for the pair of conjugate roots $a\pm ib$ look like $x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2=(x-a)^2+b^2$.  We can observe that this polynomial has no real roots and its sign doesn't change (if its sign were to change, then, by the intermediate value theorem, it would have a root).

Therefore, sign changes, when the polynomial is evaluated on the reals, are completely determined by the real roots.

Comment: Then sign changes with only real roots altough there are complex roots? (I have to be sure :))

Comment: By the intermediate value theorem, each sign change corresponds to a root.  So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to well understand your question, but clearly the existence of complex roots of a polynomial effects the distribution of signs of the polynomial for real values of the variable.

You well know, I think, that a second degree polynomial has always the same sign if it has complex roots, but change sign if it has real distinct roots.